# Fuseki how to add Pellet reasoner

Tags: java, jena, owl, fuseki, pellet

I want to use pellet reasoner with my Fuseki 2.3.1

First: I added Pellet reasoner to my config.ttl as this:

```
ja:reasoner
        [ ja:reasonerClass
        "org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory";]
```

So now I have to add the jar for Pellet to fuseki

This page explains how to add jars (not specificaly pellete) to fuseki

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/permissions/example.html

So I commet this line

> exec $JAVA $JVM_ARGS -jar "$JAR" "$@"

and I uncommet this line

> java $JVM_ARGS -cp "$JAR:$APPJAR" org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd "$@"

and uncomment the line that starts with `APPJAR=`

now I still need to **know** and **download** the jars for Pellete, I found this link https://datababel.wordpress.com/2013/06/26/fuseki-using-pellet-inference/ that says which are the jars,

I downloaded the lastest **available** version from maven, which are:

pellet-jena-ignazio1977-2.4.0-ignazio1977.jar

pellet-rules-2.3.6-ansell.jar

pellet-el-2.3.6-ansell.jar

pellet-datatypes-2.3.6-ansell.jar

pellet-core-ignazio1977-2.4.0-ignazio1977.jar

aterm-java-1.8.2-p1.jar

commons-collections4-4.1-javadoc.jar

commons-collections4-4.1.jar

and I added them to fuseki-server script like this:

```
APPJAR=pellet-jena-ignazio1977-2.4.0-ignazio1977.jar:pellet-rules-2.3.6-ansell.jar:pellet-el-2.3.6-ansell.jar:pellet-datatypes-2.3.6-ansell.jar:pellet-core-ignazio1977-2.4.0-ignazio1977.jar:aterm-java-1.8.2-p1.jar:commons-collections4-4.1-javadoc.jar:commons-collections4-4.1.jar
```

(they are in the home directory of fuseki)

I run ./fuseki-server, and I get this error

```
[2016-03-30 16:49:06] Server     INFO  Fuseki 2.3.1 2015-12-08T09:24:07+0000
[2016-03-30 16:49:07] Config     INFO  FUSEKI_HOME=/usr/local/apache-jena-fuseki-2.3.1
[2016-03-30 16:49:07] Config     INFO  FUSEKI_BASE=/usr/local/apache-jena-fuseki-2.3.1/run
[2016-03-30 16:49:07] Servlet    INFO  Initializing Shiro environment
[2016-03-30 16:49:07] Config     INFO  Shiro file: file:///usr/local/apache-jena-fuseki-2.3.1/run/shiro.ini
[2016-03-30 16:49:07] Config     INFO  Load configuration: file:///usr/local/apache-jena-fuseki-2.3.1/run/configuration/config.ttl
[2016-03-30 16:49:07] AssemblerHelp WARN  ja:loadClass: Migration to Jena3: Converting com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDB to org.apache.jena.tdb.TDB
[2016-03-30 16:49:07] Server     ERROR Exception in initialization: com/hp/hpl/jena/reasoner/ReasonerFactory
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hp/hpl/jena/reasoner/ReasonerFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.loadClass(AssemblerBase.java:109)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.ReasonerFactoryAssembler.getReasonerFactoryByClassName(ReasonerFactoryAssembler.java:140)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.ReasonerFactoryAssembler.getReasonerFactory(ReasonerFactoryAssembler.java:131)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.ReasonerFactoryAssembler.open(ReasonerFactoryAssembler.java:50)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.openBySpecificType(AssemblerGroup.java:130)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:117)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$ExpandingAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:81)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:39)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:35)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.InfModelAssembler.getReasonerFactory(InfModelAssembler.java:53)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.InfModelAssembler.getReasoner(InfModelAssembler.java:46)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.InfModelAssembler.openEmptyModel(InfModelAssembler.java:34)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.ModelAssembler.openModel(ModelAssembler.java:36)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.ModelAssembler.open(ModelAssembler.java:43)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.openBySpecificType(AssemblerGroup.java:130)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:117)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$ExpandingAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:81)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:39)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:35)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup.openModel(AssemblerGroup.java:35)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.core.assembler.DatasetAssembler.createDataset(DatasetAssembler.java:59)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.core.assembler.DatasetAssembler.open(DatasetAssembler.java:43)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.openBySpecificType(AssemblerGroup.java:130)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:117)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$ExpandingAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:81)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:39)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:35)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.Builder.buildDataService(Builder.java:75)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.Builder.buildDataAccessPoint(Builder.java:60)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.FusekiConfig.readConfiguration(FusekiConfig.java:249)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.FusekiConfig.readConfigurationDirectory(FusekiConfig.java:223)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiServer.initializeDataAccessPoints(FusekiServer.java:212)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiServerListener.init(FusekiServerListener.java:78)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiServerListener.contextInitialized(FusekiServerListener.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.jetty.JettyFuseki.start(JettyFuseki.java:120)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd$FusekiCmdInner.exec(FusekiCmd.java:359)
    at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainMethod(CmdMain.java:93)
    at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:58)
    at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:45)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd$FusekiCmdInner.innerMain(FusekiCmd.java:95)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd.main(FusekiCmd.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.ReasonerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 71 more
```

Any help please

#### Hint: I dont know if what I tried is correct of not, all I want is to include Pellet reasoner into fuseki

#### Update

After ignazio told me that I am mixing the jars,

I went to Pellet git hut and download the src and used maven to complie and get the jars

Then I changed the jar that I am using to :

```
commons-collections4-4.1-javadoc.jar:commons-collections4-4.1.jar:pellet-cli-2.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:jena-core-2.13.0.jar:pellet-jena-2.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:pellet-modularity-2.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:pellet-owlapi-2.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:pellet-pellint-2.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

but I got this exception:

```
[2016-03-30 17:42:09] AssemblerHelp WARN  ja:loadClass: Migration to Jena3: Converting com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDB to org.apache.jena.tdb.TDB
[2016-03-30 17:42:10] RDFDefaultErrorHandler WARN  unknown-source: {W136} Relative URIs are not permitted in RDF: specifically <ont-policy.rdf>
[2016-03-30 17:42:10] Server     ERROR Exception in initialization: expected class org.apache.jena.reasoner.ReasonerFactory, but had class org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory
[2016-03-30 17:42:10] WebAppContext WARN  Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@5bcde458{/,file:///usr/local/apache-jena-fuseki-2.3.1/webapp/,STARTING}
org.apache.jena.assembler.exceptions.NotExpectedTypeException: expected class org.apache.jena.reasoner.ReasonerFactory, but had class org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory
  doing:
    root: 79f74f0ed3a21ef24b1cbccda7d37b62 with type: http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#ReasonerFactory assembler class: class org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.ReasonerFactoryAssembler
    root: file:///usr/local/apache-jena-fuseki-2.3.1/run/configuration/config.ttl#model_inf with type: http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#InfModel assembler class: class org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.InfModelAssembler
    root: file:///usr/local/apache-jena-fuseki-2.3.1/run/configuration/config.ttl#dataset with type: http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#RDFDataset assembler class: class org.apache.jena.sparql.core.assembler.DatasetAssembler

    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.ReasonerFactoryAssembler.mustBeReasonerFactory(ReasonerFactoryAssembler.java:169)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.ReasonerFactoryAssembler.getReasonerFactoryByClassName(ReasonerFactoryAssembler.java:141)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.ReasonerFactoryAssembler.getReasonerFactory(ReasonerFactoryAssembler.java:131)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.ReasonerFactoryAssembler.open(ReasonerFactoryAssembler.java:50)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.openBySpecificType(AssemblerGroup.java:130)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:117)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$ExpandingAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:81)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:39)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:35)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.InfModelAssembler.getReasonerFactory(InfModelAssembler.java:53)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.InfModelAssembler.getReasoner(InfModelAssembler.java:46)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.InfModelAssembler.openEmptyModel(InfModelAssembler.java:34)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.ModelAssembler.openModel(ModelAssembler.java:36)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.ModelAssembler.open(ModelAssembler.java:43)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.openBySpecificType(AssemblerGroup.java:130)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:117)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$ExpandingAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:81)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:39)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:35)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup.openModel(AssemblerGroup.java:35)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.core.assembler.DatasetAssembler.createDataset(DatasetAssembler.java:59)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.core.assembler.DatasetAssembler.open(DatasetAssembler.java:43)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.openBySpecificType(AssemblerGroup.java:130)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:117)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$ExpandingAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:81)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:39)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:35)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.Builder.buildDataService(Builder.java:75)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.Builder.buildDataAccessPoint(Builder.java:60)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.FusekiConfig.readConfiguration(FusekiConfig.java:249)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.FusekiConfig.readConfigurationDirectory(FusekiConfig.java:223)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiServer.initializeDataAccessPoints(FusekiServer.java:212)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiServerListener.init(FusekiServerListener.java:78)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiServerListener.contextInitialized(FusekiServerListener.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.jetty.JettyFuseki.start(JettyFuseki.java:120)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd$FusekiCmdInner.exec(FusekiCmd.java:359)
    at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainMethod(CmdMain.java:93)
    at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:58)
    at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:45)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd$FusekiCmdInner.innerMain(FusekiCmd.java:95)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd.main(FusekiCmd.java:60)
[2016-03-30 17:42:10] Server     INFO  Started 2016/03/30 17:42:10 WEST on port 3030
```

Comment: You're mixing up versions. The ansell and ignazio1977 versions are from two distinct forks. Pick one or the other, not both.

Comment: @Ignazio do you mean for all these jars ? `aterm-java`, `pellet-core` , `pellet-datatypes` , `pellet-el` , `pellet-jena` ,and `pellet-rules` ? any place please to download them all to be sure i use the correct ones ?

Comment: @Ignazio for example `pellet-rules` is just available for ansell, there is no ignazio version for it

Comment: They come from different pellet versions, so some modules might have changed. Pellet-rules might have been merged in the main pellet repository.

Comment: The error you're seeing is characteristic of version conflicts. To fix, the first thing is to remove known incompatibilities. Start with picking one version and see what else happens. All the jars for both versions are available on maven central.

Comment: @Ignazio Oh I didn't see that you made a new comment, I was trying to find the correct jars as you said, kindly could you check my updated question? now I got the jars from Pellet github, will that be wrong please? but I still get the problem :(

Comment: @Ignazio help please

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
Use [openllet](https://github.com/Galigator/openllet) instead.
Just change to `ja:reasonerClass "openllet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory"` in the config file, and download the openllet distribution and other jar files needed to the classpath.

Explanation:The error

`expected class org.apache.jena.reasoner.ReasonerFactory, but had class org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory`

is caused by that the pellet's `org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory` implements the old interface (`com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.ReasonerFactory`) which is different from the interface used in Fuseki (`org.apache.jena.reasoner.ReasonerFactory`).

The openllet's `openllet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory` implements the correct interface (`org.apache.jena.reasoner.ReasonerFactory`).

Check their source code:

[openllet's PelletReasonerFactory.java](https://github.com/Galigator/openllet/blob/9c5928a4b49c83e69889ab2894036494e5c95a0d/module-jena/src/main/java/openllet/jena/PelletReasonerFactory.java)

[pellet's PelletReasonerFactory.java](https://github.com/stardog-union/pellet/blob/master/jena/src/main/java/org/mindswap/pellet/jena/PelletReasonerFactory.java)

Answer (score 0):

The error you have is

`expected class org.apache.jena.reasoner.ReasonerFactory, but had class org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory`

I'm no expert but it looks like the Pellet factory for Jena currently in your classpath does not match the expected class.

Which version of Jena comes with Fuseki, and which version is currently used by Pellet?