# Error when using Pellet reasoner with Fuseki server

Tags: jena, owl, fuseki, pellet

I try to launch Fuseki server with Pellet reasoner and Jena. I found [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313972/fuseki-how-to-add-pellet-reasoner) that had similar issue, however (1) my error message is different, and (2) it looks like the final solution was not provided in the referenced thread.

The problem is that Fuseki says

```
no reasoner called file:///home/gosper/Desktop/tools/jena-fuseki1-1.3.1/org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory
```

It's not clear why it points to this root, where I obviously do not have a file called as `org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory`.

This is my `config.ttl` file and I start Fuseki server as follows:

```
./fuseki-server --update --config=config.ttl
```

**config.ttl**

```
# Licensed under the terms of http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
## Basic Fuseki configuation file.
##
## See also config-tdb.ttl for TDB specific examples.
## See also config-examples.ttl for commented examples.

@prefix : <#> .
@prefix fuseki: <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix tdb: <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .
@prefix ja: <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .

[] rdf:type fuseki:Server ;

fuseki:services (

<#tdb>

) .

# Custom code.
[] ja:loadClass "com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDB" .

########################################################################

# TDB
<#tdb> rdf:type fuseki:Service ;
fuseki:name "tdb" ; # http://localhost：3030/tdb
fuseki:serviceQuery "query" ; # SPARQL query service
fuseki:serviceQuery "sparql" ; # SPARQL query service
fuseki:serviceUpdate "update" ; # SPARQL query service
fuseki:serviceUpload "upload" ; # Non-SPARQL upload service
fuseki:serviceReadGraphStore "get"; # SPARQL Graph store protocol (read only)
fuseki:dataset <#dataset2> ; #select which set to
. #use
tdb:GraphTDB rdfs:subClassOf ja:Model .

<#dataset2> rdf:type ja:RDFDataset ;
ja:defaultGraph <#model2>;
.

<#model2> a ja:InfModel;
ja:baseModel <#tdbGraph>;
ja:reasoner
[ ja:reasonerURL
<org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory>];
.
<#tdbGraph> rdf:type tdb:GraphTDB;
tdb:location "DB";
.
```

I downloaded all the necessary Jena libraries from [here](https://semtools.ecoinformatics.org/repository/dev/sms/lib) and added them to Fuseki root directory as described [here](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/permissions/example.html). Finally my modified fuseki-server script looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

export FUSEKI_HOME="${FUSEKI_HOME:-$PWD}"

if [ ! -e "$FUSEKI_HOME" ]
then
    echo "$FUSEKI_HOME does not exist" 1>&2
    exit 1
    fi

JAR1="$FUSEKI_HOME/fuseki-server.jar"
JAR2="$FUSEKI_HOME/jena-fuseki-*-server.jar"
JAR=""

for J in "$JAR1" "$JAR2"
do
    # Expand
    J="$(echo $J)"
    if [ -e "$J" ]
    then
    JAR="$J"
    break
    fi
done

if [ "$JAR" = "" ]
then
    echo "Can't find jarfile to run"
    exit 1
fi

# Deal with Cygwin path issues
cygwin=false
case "`uname`" in
    CYGWIN*) cygwin=true;;
esac
if [ "$cygwin" = "true" ]
then
    JAR=`cygpath -w "$JAR"`
    FUSEKI_HOME=`cygpath -w "$FUSEKI_HOME"`
fi

JVM_ARGS=${JVM_ARGS:--Xmx1200M}


# By default this line should be uncommented
# exec java  $JVM_ARGS -jar "$JAR" "$@"

# By default these lines should be commented out
java $JVM_ARGS -cp "$JAR:$APPJAR" org.apache.jena.fuseki.FusekiCmd "$@"

APPJAR=aterm-java-1.6.jar:pellet-cli.jar:pellet-core.jar:pellet-datatypes.jar:pellet-dig.jar:pellet-el.jar:pellet-explanation.jar:pellet-jena.jar:pellet-modularity.jar:pellet-owlapiv3.jar:pellet-pellint.jar:pellet-query.jar:pellet-rules.jar:pellet-test.jar:commons-collections-3.2.jar
```

Now when I try to start Fuseki server, the following error appears:

```
root@gosper-HP-EliteBook-8460p:/home/gosper/Desktop/tools/jena-fuseki1-1.3.1# ./fuseki-server --update --config=config-tdb-pelletreasoner.ttl
18:30:53 WARN  ja:loadClass: Migration to Jena3: Converting com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDB to org.apache.jena.tdb.TDB
org.apache.jena.assembler.exceptions.UnknownReasonerException: no reasoner called file:///home/gosper/Desktop/tools/jena-fuseki1-1.3.1/org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory for d968cc61bfbe1366298b7276173e9fd2 [ja:reasoner of :model2]
  doing:
    root: d968cc61bfbe1366298b7276173e9fd2 with type: http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#ReasonerFactory assembler class: class org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.ReasonerFactoryAssembler
    root: file:///home/gosper/Desktop/tools/jena-fuseki1-1.3.1/config-tdb-pelletreasoner.ttl#model2 with type: http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#InfModel assembler class: class org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.InfModelAssembler
    root: file:///home/gosper/Desktop/tools/jena-fuseki1-1.3.1/config-tdb-pelletreasoner.ttl#dataset2 with type: http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#RDFDataset assembler class: class org.apache.jena.sparql.core.assembler.DatasetAssembler

    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.ReasonerFactoryAssembler.getReasonerFactoryByURL(ReasonerFactoryAssembler.java:192)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.ReasonerFactoryAssembler.getReasonerFactory(ReasonerFactoryAssembler.java:133)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.ReasonerFactoryAssembler.open(ReasonerFactoryAssembler.java:50)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.openBySpecificType(AssemblerGroup.java:130)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:117)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$ExpandingAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:81)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:39)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:35)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.InfModelAssembler.getReasonerFactory(InfModelAssembler.java:53)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.InfModelAssembler.getReasoner(InfModelAssembler.java:46)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.InfModelAssembler.openEmptyModel(InfModelAssembler.java:34)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.ModelAssembler.openModel(ModelAssembler.java:36)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.ModelAssembler.open(ModelAssembler.java:43)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.openBySpecificType(AssemblerGroup.java:130)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:117)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$ExpandingAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:81)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:39)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:35)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup.openModel(AssemblerGroup.java:35)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.core.assembler.DatasetAssembler.createDataset(DatasetAssembler.java:59)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.core.assembler.DatasetAssembler.open(DatasetAssembler.java:43)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.openBySpecificType(AssemblerGroup.java:130)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:117)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$ExpandingAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:81)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:39)
    at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:35)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiConfig.processService(FusekiConfig.java:242)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiConfig.configure(FusekiConfig.java:131)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.FusekiCmd.exec(FusekiCmd.java:448)
    at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainMethod(CmdMain.java:93)
    at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:58)
    at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:45)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.FusekiCmd.main(FusekiCmd.java:161)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ja:reasoner
        [ ja:reasonerClass
        "org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory";]
```

which is different to your assembler.

(this example is in the first link you give)

Comment: I tried so. Now it says: `org.apache.jena.assembler.exceptions.AssemblerException: caught: class name URI must start with 'java:': file:///home/gosper/Desktop/tools/jena-fuseki1-1.3.1/org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory`

Comment: Look for "java:" in the assembler.  It seems things have moved on from the description above.